# jQuery DataTables: how do I suppress row details modal upon row buttons click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with which when pressed `<tr>` I get the values and with it I show the detailed information of each row, but I have 3 final columns that have buttons and each time I press a button to show a modal of Bootstrap also shows me the detailed information of the row and I have to close that modal to see the modal of the button

I tried to get the value of the column in different ways, but the ones I found on the Internet select the td and from there they get the index, but my click event is from the `<tr>`, hence the problem

```
$('#mobis_table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var col = $(this).find('td')
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    console.log(col[i]._DT_CellIndex.column)
  }

  if (col <= 9) {

    var data = table.row(this).data();
    var id = data.id
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      }
    });
});
```

I just want to know which column was selected to avoid the details being displayed if the user clicks on the buttons of the 3 final columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your problem: when you click the button within your table row, click event bubbles down your DOM triggering click event for the row (display row details). If that is the case, you may simply do [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) within button click handler:

```js
//random source data
const srcData = [
  {item: 'apple', cat: 'fruit'},
  {item: 'pear', cat: 'fruit'},
  {item: 'cucumber', cat: 'vegie'}
];

//initialize datatables
const table = $('#example').DataTable({
  data: srcData,
  dom: 't',
  columns: ['item', 'cat'].map(header => ({title: header, data: header})),
  columnDefs: [{targets: 1, render: data => data+'<button class="good">Good button</button><button class="bad">Bad button</button>'}]
});

//emulate row click handler to display row details
$('#example').on('click', 'tr', function(){
  const rowDetails = table.row(this).data();
  console.log(rowDetails);
});

//BAD button click handler
$('#example').on('click', '.bad', function(){
  console.log('Bad button was clicked');
});

//GOOD button click handler
$('#example').on('click', '.good', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Good button was clicked');
});
```

```css
tbody button {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
 <body>
  <table id="example"></table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much if it worked, I just had to make a couple of modifications!

Comment: @CristianRuiz : you may accept the answer if it solved your problem, thus, it will be easier to those facing the same problem to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `index()` with `this`. Get total length of `tr` using `find` and `length` like below. After get total length you can easily find they are last 3 one or not with the help of `index`.

```js
$('#mobis_table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var len = $('#mobis_table').find('tr').length; // You can get total tr length here and add your logic for last 3 columns.
  var num = $(this).index();
  console.log(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='mobis_table'>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or if your click on `td` and want `tr` index use `closest()` :

```
$(this).closest("tr").index();
```

Answer (score 0):

First I had to remove the tbody from the click event of the tr, so that even pressing a button would overwrite the event.

```
$('#mobis_table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
```

Then just add the event.stopPropagation (); in the functions of my buttons.

```
$("#mobis_table").on('click', '.move-mobi', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: May I ask, why have you posted this answer with solution I already have suggested instead of simply accepting my answer? Which extra value does above code deliver?

Comment: And, by the way, having `tbody tr` instead of simply `tr` as a second parameter of your row click handler is not such a bad idea for your production app, since it will allow to ignore table header clicks.